# Example of a CW complex not homeomorphic to the realization of a simplicial set?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

I've often heard that we can give examples of CW complexes that aren't homeomorphic to the realization of any simplicial set (although I haven't heard that there exist Kan complexes that aren't isomorphic to the total singular complex of a CGWH space. Are there?)  Would someone mind providing an example of one (and an example for the opposite statement as well, if it is true)?

Comment: Heh, I just realized that we could call the "opposite statement" the "adjoint statement".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The mapping cylinder of a really messy continuous map $I\to I$

The nerve of the category in which there are two objects and each Hom set is a singleton.

Comment: What do you mean by the nerve in the second example? I thought the nerve was a simplicial set by definition, so it can't possibly provide an example of a CW-complex that doesn't come from a simplicial set.

Comment: I can't imagine why I wrote that.

Comment: Oh. That was an answer to the other part of the question.

Comment: I could have said the nerve of a nontrivial group.

Answer (score 10):

The geometric realization of a simplicial set is always triangulable. See Corollary 4.6.12 in [*Cellular Structures in Topology*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vg7Z75qqmDIC) by Fritsch and Piccinini. They also give an explicit example (in section 3.4) of a non-triangulable CW-complex (which uses, I think, essentially the same idea as Tom Goodwillie's suggestion). [This paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/u31765707336555u/) contains another example and shows, on the other hand, that every CW-complex with cells in at most two dimensions is triangulable.

Comment: The link to the paper at `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.